# How can I create multiple-level navigation using jQuery mobile?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, jquery-mobile

I have been trying to create a page using jQuery mobile.
I am trying to create a navigation menu using lists and collapsibles.
The way the navigation works is there are links and there are collections of links.
Each collection of links is put into a collapsible list.

Here is the page:

```
<div data-role="page">
<div data-role="content">
    <ul data-role="listview">
        <li> <a href="#">Link 1</a>

        </li>
        <li> <a href="#">Link 3</a>

        </li>
    </ul>
    <div data-role="collapsible" data-inset="false">
         <h3>Links inside</h3>

        <ul data-role="listview">
            <li><a href="#">link 5</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">link 6</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <ul data-role="listview">
        <li> <a href="#">Link 3</a>

        </li>
        <li> <a href="#">Link 4</a>

        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

The problem is that putting anything after a listview or collapsible seems to have some issue with padding and is slightly pushed up into the previous element, covering some of it.

I tried using <br/> [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ac3Vj/3/)
and clear:both [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ac3Vj/4/)

If possible I would like to use only one listview instead of mixing listviews and collapsible but that did not work for me.

Comment: add `data-inset="true"` to listview and collapsibles. http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/uPmC2/

Comment: I am trying to keep a similar look to my main site, which does not have rounded corners and tries to fill the entire screen

Comment: Then use this CSS `.ui-listview, .ui-collapsible { margin: 1em 0 !important; }`

Comment: After a few more tweaks I got the solution thanks, [here](http://jsfiddle.net/uPmC2/4/)